# How to avoid long pattern match based functions?

Tags: f#, ml

When using union types with quite a few constructors I almost always find myself implementing lots of logic in single function, i.e. handling all cases in one function. Sometimes I would like to extract logic for single case to separate function, but one cannot have a function accepting only one "constructor" as parameter.

Example:
Assume that we have typical "expression" type :

```
type Formula =    
| Operator of OperatorKind * Formula * Formula
| Number of double   
| Function of string * Formula list
[...]
```

Then, we would like to calculate expression :

```
let rec calculate efValues formula = 
match formula with
    | Number n -> [...] 
    | Operator (kind, lFormula, rFormula) -> [...]
    | [...]
```

Such function would  be very long and growing with every new Formula constructor.
How can I avoid that and clean up such code? Are long pattern matching constructs inevitable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extract logic for single case to separate function, but one cannot have a function accepting only one "constructor" as parameter.". Could you give an example in pseudo code?

Comment: Actually, yes, you can: `let test (Some(x)) = x` This gives a warning, but I think that is what you want right?

Comment: @mydogisbox: this will also give you a runtime exception when the pattern is not matched. I wouldn't use that for anything that has more than one case ;)

Comment: @scrwtp I'm not saying its a good idea, just that it was exactly what he was asking for: "Sometimes I would like to extract logic for single case".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the `Operator` case of the `Formula` union using an explicit tuple:

```
type Formula =    
 | Operator of (string * Formula * Formula)
 | Number of double
```

If you do this, the compiler will let you pattern match using both `Operator(name, left, right)` and using a single argument `Operator args`, so you can write something like:

```
let evalOp (name, l, r) = 0.0
let eval f = 
  match f with
 | Number n -> 0.0
 | Operator args -> evalOp args
```

I would find this a bit confusing, so it might be better to be more explicit in the type definition and use a named tuple (which is equivalent to the above):

```
type OperatorInfo = string * Formula * Formula
and Formula =    
 | Operator of OperatorInfo
 | Number of double
```

Or perhaps be even more explicit and use a record:

```
type OperatorInfo = 
 { Name : string
   Left : Formula 
   Right : Formula }
and Formula =    
 | Operator of OperatorInfo
 | Number of double
```

Then you can pattern match using one of the following:

```
| Operator args -> (...)
| Operator { Name = n; Left = l; Right = r } -> (...)
```

Comment: I took the question to mean the number of cases in the DU, rather than the number of arguments for a given case constructor. I.e., that the`calculate` function would become too long as more cases are added.

Comment: @ildjarn I think he's saying that you can define a function for each case where the input is the contents of the case by using either explicit tuples or records.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you typically want to handle all the cases in a single function. That's the main selling point of unions - they force you to handle all the cases in one way or another. That said, I can see where you're coming from.

If I had a big union and only cared about a single case, I would handle it like this, wrapping the result in an option:

```
 let doSomethingForOneCase (form: Formula) =
     match form with
     | Formula (op, l, r) -> 
         let result = (...)
         Some result
     | _ -> None
```

And then handle None in whatever way is appropriate at the call site.

Note that this is in line with the signature required by [partial active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx), so if you decide that you need to use this function as a case in another match expression, you can easily wrap it up in an active pattern to get the nice syntax.